# malloc(): memory corruption (fast)

Tags: c++, data-structures, initialization, binary-search-tree, function-definition

I just started to learn data structure and getting an error when executing

> malloc(): memory corruption (fast)

what can be the issue and how to resolve it?
I have called the following method in the main method:
This is c plus plus code

```
 struct tnode
    {
        int data;
        struct tnode* left;
        struct tnode* right;
    };
    tnode *root;
    class btree
    {
        public:
            void *insert(int val)
            {
                tnode *newnode, *ptr;
                tnode* temp = new tnode;
                temp->data = val;
                temp->left = NULL;
                temp->right = NULL;
                if (!root)
                root = newnode;
                else
                {
                    ptr = root;
                        while (ptr != NULL)
                        {
                            if (val < ptr->data)            
                            {      
                                if (ptr->left)
                                    ptr = ptr->left;
                                else
                                {
                                    ptr->left = newnode;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (val > ptr->data)
                            {
                                if (ptr->right)
                                    ptr = ptr->right;
                                else
                                {
                                    ptr->right = newnode;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cout << "Duplicate value found in tree.\n";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
};

    int main()
    {
        btree t;
        cout << "Inserting nodes.\n";   
        t.insert(5);
        t.insert(8);
        t.insert(3);
        t.insert(12);
        t.insert(9);
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of `temp` and use `newnode` instead.

Comment: The debugger is your friend. You can use it to gther information about the mistake to help you narrow down its location.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is not declaring variables in minimal scope where they are used.

```
void *insert(int val)
{
    tnode *newnode, *ptr;
    tnode* temp = new tnode;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    if (!root)
    root = newnode;
    //...
```

As you can see the variable `newnode` was not initialized but is used in this assignment:

```
root = newnode;
```

or in assignments like this:

```
ptr->left = newnode;
```

It seems you mean the pointer `temp` instead of the pointer `newnode`. At least one of the pointers is redundant.

Pay attention to that the pointer `root` should be a data member of the class `btree` including the definition of the structure `tnode`.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in C and C++ is always initialize your variables. It'll save you headaches.